# Hooded figure riddle

Tags: riddle

I had an idea for a riddle yesterday.  Here it is.

I am a horned and hooded figured, bearing a shield and blades.
The ability to control great power is in my clutch.
If you find yourself under my boot, you will discover that I am exhausted.
If I am not tired, then my boot may spare you.
You can easily choke me to death.
Does this shock you? I am shocked, too.

What am I? (and why?)

Comment: it's the second verse that makes it too easy (imo). the first verse is promising though.

Comment: Some of the lines are too easy.  Using `in my clutch` instead of `in my clutches` is a bit clumsy and is part of the giveaway.  And having obvious words like `clutch` and `choke` is too much of a giveaway.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are a:

> Car

I am a horned and hooded figured, bearing a shield and blades.

> Horn: beep, beep! 
>  Hooded: pop the hood! 
>  Shield: windshield 
>  Blades: which clear the windshield

The ability to control great power is in my clutch.

> The clutch is one of the control pedals

If you find yourself under my boot, you will discover that I am exhausted.

> If you look "under the boot" of the car... you will see the exhaust pipes.

If I am not tired, then my boot may spare you.

> If the car has a flat tyre (or no tyres) then they is often a spare tyre in the boot.

You can easily choke me to death.

> You can cause a car to "choke"

Does this shock you? I am shocked, too.

> Refers to the suspension system - the "shocks". (Is the suspension system not shocking?)

Comment: Well done.  I fear I made this too easy, but I hope it was fun.

Comment: Yes, the suspension system really shocks me too! +1 to question and answer :-)

Comment: This question is easier for Brits, as a "boot" in America doesn't have this double meaning.

Comment: @MattMalone It was fun by the way. It's the first question I've bothered to answer in many weeks. Thanks :D